# Oxyplot: Rectangles on top of HeatMapSeries

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Is it possible to create filled rectangles on top of HeatMapSeries in oxyplot? I'm able to put ScatterSeries on top, but I'm struggling with rectangles.

What I want to accomplish is to make it look like this, preferably filled with transparent pattern lines or a Bitmap:

[image]

WPF, series part:

```
<oxy:PlotView.Series>
    <oxy:HeatMapSeries Data="{Binding HeatMap}"/>
    <oxy:ScatterSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Scatter}"/>
</oxy:PlotView.Series>
```

C#, properties part:

```
public double[,] HeatMap { get; private set; }
public IList<ScatterPoint> Scatter { get; private set; }
```

Regards,
Jostein

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using four RectangleAnnotations added to PlotModel.Annotations.